# Vue: Can't render facebook messenger checkbox

Tags: facebook, vue.js

I am using Vue's single file components.  My facebook SDK is loaded but the html to loadup facebook's messenger checkbox isn't doing anything for me.  In the past using React, I've been able to use the same code that will generate a facebook iFrame.  All the values are correct and user ref is a randomly generated number, as expected.

`````
<div class="fb-messenger-checkbox"
      :origin=shopurl
      :page_id=fbPageId
      :messenger_app_id=fbAppId
      :user_ref=userRef
       prechecked="true"
       allow_login="true"
      size="medium">
</div>````
`````

Comment: You have to tell the Facebook SDK that you added a new HTML-tag on the page. So it can render it.

Comment: that was it, thanks.  I had the fbAsyncInit() defined but was never calling it.